# How do you export a .COR file from an ArcPAD checkout in GPS Pathfinder?

Tags: export, arcpad, terrasync

We use ArcPAD and sometimes Terrasync for data collection. However, when using ArcPAD, I'm finding it difficult to export data in Pathfinder from my .COR file.

Can you only check in data using the ArcPAD extension after it's collected?

We're trying to utilize the export settings from Pathfinder, and include fields like Horizontal Precision.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please [edit] your question to include the versions of Terrasync, Pathfinder, and ArcPad.

Comment: It's been years since I've used ArcPad or Terrasync, however my recollection is that ArcPad modified shapefiles or geodatabases that could be taken straight into GIS software, whereas Terrasync saved data into its own format that then required Pathfinder to download and convert into a GIS format.  I only got the `.cor` files from Pathfinder.